# Is there dataset of historical geocoordinates of ancient cities and places?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, historical

Is there a freely available dataset (csv, geojson, topojson, etc.) with geocoordinates (latitude, longitude) of ancient and tombs, for example of the towt? Ideally with additional information like population size?

I've searched Egypt but found nothing

Answer (score 1):

Basic internet search results in this github repo:

https://github.com/aourednik/historical-basemaps

and, for example, this geojson

https://github.com/aourednik/historical-basemaps/blob/master/world_bc2000.geojson

[image]